# Reading a bean which is not present in the list

Tags: spring-mvc

I hav an application-context-validation.xml

```
<bean id=x class=""/>
<bean id=y class=""/>
<bean id=z class=""/>
<bean id=w class=""/>

<util:list id="list1" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
<ref bean="x" />
<ref bean="z" />
<ref bean="y" />
</util:list>

<util:list id="list2" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
<ref bean="x" />
<ref bean="z" />
<ref bean="w" />
</util:list>
```

In the service class I Have

```
@Autowired
List<String> list1;

@Autowired
List<String> list2;
```

But When I am reading list1 all the values (x,y,z,w) is coming.

Could any one help me regarding this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your annotation in your test to use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection/map bean by unique name.

```
@Resource(name="list1")
List<String> list1;

@Resource(name="list2")
List<String> list2;
```